# Retrieve file upload data

Tags: c, cgi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *content_length = 0;
    int len = 0;
    printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");
    printf("<html><body>");
    content_length = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
    len = atoi(content_length);
    char input[len+1];
    fgets(input,len,stdin);
    puts(input);    
    printf("</body></html>");
    return 0;
}
```

I have the cgi code above. Whenever I click the submit button on my html form, it only outputs "------WebKitFormBoundaryIgcEYm5FWH1GVhkn" . It doesn't output the contents of the file uploaded. Really need help here. Stuck on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing **fgets** by **fread**.